# Classic ASP with IIS 6.0 PAGE NOT FOUND issue

Tags: asp-classic, iis-6

This is a first for me. I have an older Win 2003 R2 server running IIS6. My customer has CFM pages as well as some classic ASP pages. The CFM pages work fine. when I try to browse for the ASP pages (Remember, CLASSIC ASP NOT ASP.NET) I get a page cannot be found. If I change the extension to urlinfo.html, the page comes up with no processing of course.

I have tried the aspnet_iisreg function but the issue still happens.

any ideas on how to fix this? I am stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some classic asp with a newer version of IIS, hence it may be not relevant but still I have two ideas for your consideration.

1. In Windows Features (I'm using Win7), at World Wide Web Services\Application Development Features check whether ASP is enabled. I believe that on Win 2003 these were called the Web Service Extensions area and Active Server Pages.
2. If (1) did not help, check the Handler Mappings for your page. If the *.asp mapping is missing you should add it. In my case it is added with following options:

Request path: *.asp

Module: IsapiModule

Executable: %windir%\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll

Name: ASP_Classic (you can call it in whatever way you want)

Hope it helps!